# Download file from server php using headers

Tags: php, header, file-transfer

I have xampp web server, and trying to download file using headers! Don't know what is wrong, but file not starting to download and not appears in browser! In http response I have the source of file!

```
 header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=d:\\archive\\result.csv");
 header("Content-type: application/pdf");
 readfile("sample.pdf");
```

Can any one halp me, please!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. And then explain the actual problem _properly_. We have no idea how you are triggering this for example.

Comment: I've no idea if it is related to your problem, but the `filename` needs to be a **filename**. You can't give a complete directory path there.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file:///D:\archive\result.csv' );
```